# How can I determine the "bytes per row" of a PNG image in php?

Tags: php, image, hex, zpl

I need to know the bytes per row of a PNG image in order to use the ^DY command in ZPL. I am using PHP to generate the ZPL commands. I have a script that reads the hex data and total bytes from the PNG which is sent to my printer with the ^DY command -- but the image will not print unless I also provide the "bytes per row" of the image. How might I obtain this?

I was thinking that "bytes per row" might be the total bytes in one row of pixels so I tried using (total bytes)/(width in pixels) but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Try reading the 4-byte big-endian integer at offset 16 in the PNG file.  That is the image width, in pixels.  Then `ceil(width / 8)` is your bytes per row.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's an image, you can use [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).  It returns an array of information, of which the first two are the width and height of the image.  This will work on other supported image types, as well.

```
$info = getimagesize($file);
```

If you need more information about the file, take a look at [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).